# What is the difference between `\tl_set:Nn` and `\cs_set:Npn`?

Tags: expl3, latex3

I am newbie to LaTeX3  and i am trying to understand some basics.

So, suppose i want to do somthing like

`\newcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}`

I can achieve this by one of these ways

`\tl_const:Nn \c_myclass_contentsname_tl {Contents}`

`\tl_set:Nn \myclass_contentsname_tl {Contents}`

`\cs_set:Npn \myclass_contentsname: {Contents}`

What is the best way? is there any difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are internally more or less the same (conceptually they are *very* different), but they differ, for example, with parameter tokens:

```latex
\tl_const:Nn \c_myclass_contentsname_tl { # Contents } % works
\tl_set:Nn \l_myclass_contentsname_tl { # Contents } % works
\cs_set:Npn \myclass_contentsname: { # Contents } % breaks
```

(`\tl_new:N` + `\tl_set:Nn` and `\tl_const:Nn` are more or less the same, except that you should use the latter *only* if the contents of the token list will not ever change.)

But other than that, your really need to evaluate *what* you are defining.  Since you are defining a container for some text, and not a command to *do* something (for some definition of “do”), you want a token list, so the right way is to use a `tl`.

Use

```latex
\tl_const:Nn \c_myclass_contentsname_tl { Contents }
```

if `\c_myclass_contentsname_tl` should not be modified, or

```latex
\tl_new:N \l_myclass_contentsname_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_myclass_contentsname_tl { Contents }
```

if the user can change the token list if needed.

Comment: So here i think it's `\tl_set:Nn` no?

Comment: @studentmaths I think so, yes.  Definitely not `\cs_set:Npn`.  The choice between `set` and `const` is if the contents will change.  From the looks of your example, it seems `set` is more appropriate, yes

Comment: What is the meaning of `tl`? TeX LaTeX? I mean, the letters `tl`.

Comment: @Sigur Token List